# Background image for a label in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview, under a item template I have a table, one of the row of the table look like this

```
<td bgcolor="White" colspan="2" style="width:100%; background-image:url(bubble1.gif);">
<asp:Panel  ID="pnlHistory"  runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto">
 <asp:Label  ID="lblHistory" runat="server" Text='<%# Server.HtmlDecode(Eval("History").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
</td>

</tr>
```

I want to display bubble image as a background, on which my text [i.e. History (coming from database)] will be displayed.

Comment: I forget to add: "The above code I am using is not displaying the Image as a background, in fact it's not showing that image anywhere".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, I am using Jquery bubble for the same..

This is truly strange that I haven't get any suggestion at stackoverflow for my question, instead I got a missing tag statement...

Anyways, I am posting this answer because I have resolved the issue and if anyone else is looking for the same , then this answer might proof helpful for them.